# Terminating application and ScheduledExecutorService; Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduled-tasks

I have the following logic (simplified):

```
public class Application {

    public static volatile boolean stopServer;
    private static ScheduledExecutorService taskScheduler;

    private static Thread listenerThread;

    public static synchronized void switchStopServer() {
        stopServer = true;

        listenerThread.interrupt();
        taskScheduler.shutdownNow();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            int threadPoolSize = 4;
            taskScheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(threadPoolSize);

            listenerThread = new ListenerThread();
            taskScheduler.schedule(listenerThread, 0, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
    }

}

public class ListenerThread extends Thread {

    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Socket socketConnection;

    @Override
    public void run() {
         while (!Application.stopServer) {
              try {
                   socketConnection = serverSocket.accept();
                   new CommunicatorThread(socketConnection).start();
              } catch (SocketException e) {
              } catch (Exception e) {
              }
         }  
    }

    private static void closeServerSocket() {
         try {
              if (serverSocket != null && !serverSocket.isClosed()) serverSocket.close();
         } catch (Exception e) { }
    }

    @Override
    public void interrupt() {
         closeServerSocket();
         super.interrupt();
    }

}
```

What I want to achieve, is to terminate `Thread`s the proper way. First of all, is this (`switchStopServer()`) the correct way to do that, or are there any better solutions?

I'm a little confused with the [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html), because `shutdownNow()` does not interrupt the `Thread`s, neither does [`ScheduledFuture.cancel(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel%28boolean%29) (at least for me it doesn't), so I can't interrupt `ServerSocket.accept()`. I know, in my example there is no need for the `ScheduledExecutorService`, but in my real application there is.

Comment: Why are you listening on a ServerSocket in a scheduled way? Any specific reason? The design could be much simpler if you had a single dedicated thread listening on a ServerSocket in a tight loop and handling off new connections to new spawned threads, or a an executor service.

Comment: @Zaki I thought, since I'm starting other threads in a scheduled way, I will just use the same pool to start all threads, so when it is time for termination I just call `shutdownNow()`. But you are right, I should not schedule them at all. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem I believe is that you are confusing `Thread` and `Runnable`.  Even though `ListenerThread` extends `Thread`, it is actually *not* it's own thread.  The thread is managed by the `ExecutorService` thread-pool which is just calling your `run()` method.  This is only [sort of] working because `Thread` also implements `Runnable`.  When you call `ListenerThread.interrupt()` you are not interrupting the thread in the thread-pool although you are calling your `interrupt()` method but just directly in the calling thread.  This should close the socket since it calls `closeServerSocket()` from the outside.

When you call `ScheduledFuture.cancel(true)` or `shutdownNow()`, the *pool* thread(s) should be interrupted but this will *not* call your `interrupt()` method there.  You can test for the interruption by using `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` in your `run()` method.

You should change `ListenerThread` from extending `Thread` and instead have it just implement `Runnable` (**see edit below**).   You will want to do something like the following loop in your `run()` method:

```
while (!Application.stopServer && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
```

To interrupt the `accept()` method, you are going to have to close the `serverSocket` from another thread.  Most likely this will be done by the thread that is calling `interrupt()`.  It should close the socket, `shutdownNow()` or `cancel()` the thread-pool, and then it can wait for the pool to terminate.

**Edit:**

Actually, I wonder why you are using a pool for your `ListenerThread` since there will only ever be one of them, it is being scheduled immediately, and it is just starting a new thread on any connection directly.  I would remove your `taskScheduler` pool entirely, keep `ListenerThread` extending `Thread`, and just call `new ListenerThread().start();`.

The outer thread would still just close the `serverSocket` to stop the `ListenerThread`.  If you also need to close all of the connections as well then the `ListenerThread` needs to keep a collection of the `socketConnection` around so it can call `close()` on them when the `accept()` throws a n `IOException`.

Also, currently you have `private Socket socketConnection;` which is misleading because it will change after every call to `accept()`.  I'd rewrite it as:

```
 Socket socketConnection = serverSocket.accept();
 new CommunicatorThread(socketConnection).start();
```

Comment: Still a little confused. In debug the interrupt method is actually called, and the application terminates successfully. If I change to `Runnable`, how should I interrupt the `accept()` command?

Comment: Yeah sorry @Daniel.  `interrupt()` is being called but directly in the calling thread -- not from the thread in the thread-pool.  This means that you will have synchronization issues.

Comment: @Daniel You are going to need to close the `serverSocket` from the outside of your thread -- most likely from the same thread which is trying to do the interrupt.

Comment: Couple more edit to my answer @Daniel as I process your code more.

Comment: Thanks, nice suggestions. Check my comment below the question, it explains the scheduler. What is the correct way to keep track of the `Thread`s and call `closeServerSocket()` if I need to? I mean, it smells dirty to store them in static variables. Should I start a separate `Thread` for this purpose?

Comment: The `serverSocket` and associated thread should be keep by the caller.  If the main thread created the socket then it should be a field in the main class.  Same with the `ListenerThread`.  If you want the `ListenerThread` to "own" the socket then just remove the `static` on it.  You can add a `close()` method onto `ListenerThread` so that main would do `listener.close();`.

Comment: Thanks again, I understand these things much better now :)

Comment: Time for a revival, I have a question again: At the moment I'm using a `Runnable` called `mainThread` which has any other `Runnable` and `ExecutorService` set as a property. If I initialize a new `Runnable`, I pass the `mainThread` instance to it, so if I want to terminate the application I call `mainThread.stop()` from inside the 'child', which then of course tries to stop the other `Runnable`s stored as properties. At this point, when the `stop()` occurs, `mainThread` has finished it's `run()` method, but this means it is still a live instance and I'm able to make method calls to it, right?

Comment: Just because the `Thread` has finished @Daniel, doesn't mean the object has been somehow invalidated.  So yes, you can make method calls to it.